# Tracking click events

Tags: javascript

Three different pie charts will appear at different values. (Between $1 - $1000, $1000 - $5000 and above $5000)

When I click a risk level at one pie chart, how do I keep that risk level when I switch to a different pie chart.

**Original risk level**

[image: original risk level]

**How do I keep the risk level when I slide to a new pie?**

[image: how do I keep the risk level when I slide to a new pie?]

```
    $(".slide").on("change", function() {
  var a = (this.value);


  if (a < 999) {

    $('#three, #two, #risk-label-full, #risk-label-four').hide();
    $('#one, #tolerancelist_two, #risk-label-two').show();


  } else if (a >= 1000 && a <= 5000) {
    $('#risk-label-full').on('click', function(evt) {
        $('#risk-label-four').show();
        return false;//Returning false prevents the event from continuing up the chain
    });
    $('#one, #three, #risk-label-two, #risk-label-full').hide();
    $('#two, #tolerancelist_four, #risk-label-four').show();
  } else if (a >= 5001) {

    $('#two, #one, #risk-label-four, #risk-label-two').hide();
    $('#three, #tolerancelist_full, #risk-label-full').show();
  }


  if (a == 10000) {
    $('#slider-plus').show();
  } else if (a <= 9999) {
    $('#slider-plus').hide();
  }

});


      $(".tolerancerisk_two").click(function(e) {
        if( $(this).hasClass("active") ) {
            $(this).removeClass("active").addClass("closed");
        } else {
            // if other menus are open remove open class and add closed
            $(this).siblings().removeClass("active").addClass("closed");
            $(this).removeClass("closed").addClass("active");
        }
  });

  $(".tolerancerisk_four").click(function(e) {

        if( $(this).hasClass("active") ) {
            $(this).removeClass("active").addClass("closed");
        } else {
            // if other menus are open remove open class and add closed
            $(this).siblings().removeClass("active").addClass("closed");
            $(this).removeClass("closed").addClass("active");
        }
  });

$(".tolerancerisk_full").click(function(e) {

      if( $(this).hasClass("active") ) {
          $(this).removeClass("active").addClass("closed");
      } else {
          // if other menus are open remove open class and add closed
          $(this).siblings().removeClass("active").addClass("closed");
          $(this).removeClass("closed").addClass("active");
      }
});
```

Comment: does my question make sense at least